# Как плавно нарисовать фигуру с помощью Canvas и JS?

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas

**Хочу нарисовать квадрат с плавными углами, но чтобы все это происходило постепенно(анимированно)**:

1. рисуется верхняя сторона фигуры;
2. рисуется переход в виде плавного угла на правую сторону фигуры;
3. рисуется переход в виде плавного угла на правую сторону фигуры;
4. рисуется правая сторона квадрата;
5. снова плавный переход на нижнюю сторону квадрата;
6. рисуется нижняя сторона;
7. плавный переход на левую сторону;
8. снова плавный переход на верхнюю сторону;
9. фигура готова

Анимация делается с помощью requestAnimationFrame.

```js
let can = document.getElementById('can');
let ctx = can.getContext('2d');
/*
//  Вот так должен выглядеть квадрат в итоге
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(250,250);
ctx.lineTo(350,250);
ctx.arcTo(360,250,360,260,10);
ctx.lineTo(360,350);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(360,350);
ctx.lineTo(360,450);
ctx.arcTo(360,460,340,460,10);
ctx.lineTo(250,460);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(250,460);
ctx.lineTo(150,460);
ctx.arcTo(140,460,140,450,10);
ctx.lineTo(140,360);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(140,360);
ctx.lineTo(140,260);
ctx.arcTo(140,250,150,250,10);
ctx.lineTo(250,250);
ctx.stroke();
*/


// вот что я делаю
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(250,250);// начальные точки рисования.


animate({
  duration: 3000,
    timing(timeFraction) {
        return timeFraction;
    },
    draw(progress) {
        ctx.lineTo(progress*350,250);//рисуется верхняя   сторона фигуры.Странно, что основная часть линии уже нарисована. Если изменить moveTo(0,250), то работает как надо
    ctx.arcTo(progress*360,250,360,progress*260,10);//Должен быть плавный переход,вместо этого получается что-то непонятное
        ctx.stroke();
    
    }
})

// Функция плавного рисования
function animate({timing, draw, duration}) {
    // Вычисляем начальное время с нчачала загрузки страницы
  let start = performance.now();

  requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
    // timeFraction изменяется от 0 до 1
    let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;
    console.log('timeFraction = '+timeFraction);
    if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

    // вычисление текущего состояния анимации
    let progress = timing(timeFraction);
    console.log('progress = '+progress);

    draw(progress); // отрисовать её

    if (timeFraction < 1) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

  });
}
```

```html
  <canvas id="can" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Вот мой код на codePen: https://codepen.io/GregoMur/pen/RwKqvVY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разбил фигуру на 8 частей (стороны и арки), собрал 8 функций в массив, каждая из которых получает параметр - свой прогресс от 0 до 1 и рисует необходимую часть.

Анимация идет последовательно, значит реально надо считать только прогресс одного куска. Все предыдущие будут рисоваться полностью, все последующие - пропускаться.

А как узнать, какой по счету кусок надо рисовать частично?

Посчитал весь периметр: `4 стороны + 2πR`. Зная длину каждого куска, можно в цикле считать сумму длин, пока `(сумма_длин / весь_периметр) < общий_прогресс_фигуры`

Ваши числа вынес в отдельные параметры, чтобы можно было так анимировать любые квадраты / прямоугольники с любыми углами.

Конечно, не приятно каждый раз вникать в такое и вручную прописывать координаты. Поэтому зная контекст всей задачи, желательно один раз помучиться и создать более абстрактую функцию, которая спрячет от вас все вычисления. Кажется, на SVG такое делается за пару строчек. Если недельку с этим повозиться, наверняка можно придумать функцию, которая получает SVG - path строку, разбирает её и анимирует линии в canvas.

```js
let draw_fn = (function () {
  let PI = Math.PI;

  let wid = 120, hei = 120;
  let x = 10, y = 10; // отступ от верхнего левого угла canvas
  let r = 10; // border-radius

  let side_x = wid - 2 * r;
  let side_y = hei - 2 * r;
  let arc_length = (PI * r) / 2; // (длина окружности / 4)

  let perimeter = 2 * (side_x + side_y) + (2 * PI * r);

  // Рубрика «Хрень с координатами»
  let func_list = [
    // Массив функций, которые должны вызываться для последовательной
    // отрисовки всех восьми компонентов фигуры.
    // _p { от 0 до 1 }: Какую часть компонента надо нарисовать.
    
    (_p) => line( // верхняя сторона
      x + r,
      y,
      x + r + _p * side_x,
      y
    ),
    (_p) => arc( // угол - верх - право
      x + r + side_x,
      y + r,
      r,
      1.5 * PI,
      (1.5 + 0.5 * _p) * PI
    ),

    (_p) => line( // правая сторона
      x + wid,
      y + r,
      x + wid,
      y + r + _p * side_y
    ),
    (_p) => arc( // угол - вниз - право
      x + r + side_x,
      y + r + side_y,
      r,
      0,
      (0.5 * _p) * PI
    ),

    (_p) => line( // нижняя сторона
      x + r + side_x,
      y + hei,
      x + r + (1 - _p) * side_x,
      y + hei
    ),
    (_p) => arc( // угол - вниз - лево
      x + r,
      y + r + side_y,
      r,
      0.5 * PI,
      (0.5 + 0.5 * _p) * PI
    ),

    (_p) => line( // левая сторона
      x,
      y + r + side_y,
      x,
      y + r + (1 - _p) * side_y
    ),
    (_p) => arc( // угол - верх - лево
      x + r,
      y + r,
      r,
      PI,
      (1 + 0.5 * _p) * PI
    ),
  ];

  let line_list = [
    // Список длин всех компонентов.
    side_x, arc_length,
    side_y, arc_length,
    side_x, arc_length,
    side_y, arc_length,
  ];

  let ctx = null;

  return function (cnv_context, progress) {
    ctx = cnv_context;

    let total_length = 0; // Длина всей линии, которую надо сейчас нарисовать.
    let draw_index = 0; // Сколько функций из массива необходимо вызвать.
    let last_component_progress = 1;
    // Реально надо посчитать только прогресс последнего компонента.    
    // Прогресс всех предыдущих будет 1.

    for (let line_length of line_list) {
      total_length += line_length;

      /*
        Допустим, длина первого куска = 0.2 часть всего периметра,
        второго = 0.05 часть всего,

        прилетел progress = 0.24

        Надо нарисовать первый кусок полностью,
        и 0.04 / 0.05 = 0.8 часть второго куска
      */
      let total_part = total_length / perimeter;

      if (total_part >= progress) {
        //     0.05
        let curr_part = line_length / perimeter;

        //     0.04           0.24   - (   0.25    -   0.05   )
        let progress_part = progress - (total_part - curr_part);

        last_component_progress = progress_part / curr_part;
        break;
      }

      draw_index++;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < draw_index; i++) {
      // Все куски рисуем целиком
      func_list[i](1);
    }

    // И необходимую часть последнего куска.
    func_list[draw_index](last_component_progress);
  }

  /***/

  function line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  function arc(cx, cy, r, start, end) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, r, start, end);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
})();

/*** Ваш код ниже почти не трогал. Только две строчки */
let can = document.getElementById('can');
let ctx = can.getContext('2d');

animate({
  duration: 3000,
  timing(timeFraction) {
    return timeFraction;
  },
  draw: draw_fn,
});

// Функция плавного рисования
function animate({ timing, draw, duration }) {
  let start = performance.now();

  requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
    let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;

    if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

    let progress = timing(timeFraction);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height); // <--
    draw(ctx, progress); // <--

    if (timeFraction < 1) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)